# What does Button.PerformClick do?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I know this might be a trivial question, but I was just wondering whether there is any advantage of calling [`Button.PerformClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx) rather than invoking the click event of a button directly. The MSDN documentation simply says:

> Generates a Click event for a button.

Does this mean it simply does the same thing as calling the click event of the button or is there some other special advantage?

Comment: It calls the event handler for that button.

Comment: MSDN seems pretty straight forward to me `Remarks: This method can be called to raise the Click event.`

Comment: I think it would be interesting to know exactly why `PerformClick()` exists. The MSDN documentation is too vague.

Comment: @JasonEvans Unit testing?

Comment: @dialer, I came here because my NUnit test was failing because PerformClick() did not actually performed a click. Test passed once I called handler directly. My guess is that the method just imitates mouse click but GUI is frozen while tests are executing so it doesn't work...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An external caller who knows nothing of the subscribed events cannot simply call the click handler - and events do not allow you to obtain information about subscribers. So this method allows separation of concerns, so that external callers can "play nice".

Additionally:

- it ensures that any polymorphism on the virtual method is applied
- it applies any rules - for example: is the button disabled

If you do know about the event-handler, and you aren't using polymorphism, and you don't care whether it is disabled, and you don't need to worry about event-handlers you don't already know about - then by all means : just call the event-handler method.

Comment: Is PerformClick synchronous?

Comment: @beppe9000 no idea; you'd have to try it