# How to raise an event to selectively target an event handler

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, throw

I have two buttons and a textbox.  When I click button 1 I want the event handler to raise an event that will make button 2 think it has been clicked. I want to do this without giving button 1 and 2 the same event handler.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // What do I put here that would get to the button2_click handler? 
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "button 2 clicked";
    }
}
```

The code above is a feasibility test I want to prove.  The goal is to eventually have a multi-form application where a button clicked on form1 triggers the button_click event handler for a button on form2.

Comment: sounds like very poor design, but why not just call the other event handler(s) directly from the first one?

Comment: This is just a first pass to get the code roughed in.  How would you get two button click events in DIFFERENT forms to share the same event handler?

Answer (score 0):

There is one more alternative way to this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("1 clicked");
            button2.PerformClick();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("2 clicked");
        }
    }
```

**what does button2.PerformClick does?**

See the very good answer here => [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18154249/1505865)

Comment: The difference would be if you cared about who the sender was inside the button2_Click event (sender will be button2 if you call PerformClick).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the eventhandlers generated by the designer(use the designer to do that or it wont be removed from the designer.cs) and and implement your own and hook it to the 2 events by hand like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Click += myEventHandler;
        button2.Click += myEventHandler;
    }

    private void myEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "button 2 clicked";
    }
}
```